# How to regex first letter of each word perl

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep out just the first letters of a string.

```
my $string = Bank Of America;
# I tried this
my $newstring = grep (/\b(\w)+/, $string);
```

All this gives me is the "Bank" not even B. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this under `grep`?  What are you trying to do altogether?

Comment: Btw, what you posted isn't valid: your 'string' has to be quoted somehow.

Comment: "grep out" is confusing; can you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: 1. That code doesn't do what you say at all (and that's ignoring the mistake that prevents it from even compiling). 2. It's not clear what you want to do. How about if you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (remove `+`)

```
(\b\w)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cU8iA0/2)

Answer (score 0):

Though you got an answer, you are not doing it right: there is really no need to use a heavyweight like grep; use instead =~ to associate your string with the pattern match. You don't need \b either as this is only needed to limit the search to whole words, while you only want a character. The result will then be stored in $1.

```
    my $string = "Bank Of America";
    $string =~ /(\w)/;
    print "$1\n";
```